# How to delete an interstitial iAd

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad, interstitial

I am implementing interstitial iAds into my project. After each game, I attempt to show an interstitial ad. However, in my testing, I get an error saying that there are too many interstitial ads after about 10 games. How do I delete these instances of interstitial ads?

Code:

```
if requestingAd == false {
    showInterstitialAds = true
    self.interstitialAd.delegate = self
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic
    println("Loading Ad")
    requestingAd = true
}
```

Also, I am attempting to show an interstitial ad after each play of my game. However, sometimes an ad is not shown and I believe this is normal because the ad inventory might not always be available. As a result, the game often ends without showing an ad.

Is there a way that I can detect if an interstitial ad will not be shown so that I can use a banner ad instead?

Comment: You need to show some code.

Answer (score -2):

You can't delete  interstitial   but you can cancel it before showing next interstitial using this method

[interstitial cancelAction];

Comment: Don't answer things when you don't know the answer... cancelAction cancel's a tap action, not removes the adView.